# Jython change name of file

Tags: jython

I have a file that has a name 'foo.bill.me.txt' in a dir, and the same dir also has a file named 'foo.txt'. I want to rename 'foo.bill.me.txt' to 'foo.txt', and have the original 'foo.txt' clobbered, then delete 'foo.bill.me.txt'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this really jython tagged.  If so, just use the python [os module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)

This should perform the atomic operation in unix flavors:

```
os.rename('foo.bill.me.txt','foo.txt')
```

If under windows, the docs for rename state:

> On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be raised even if it is a file; there may be no way to implement an atomic rename when dst names an existing file.

therefore on windows you need the two step "non atomic"

```
os.remove('foo.txt')
os.rename('foo.bill.me.txt','foo.txt')
```